# Adding frozenset to set of other frozensets

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, frozenset

I am trying to add a frozenset to an already existing set of frozensets however when i try to use the add() function to add it the return is None. I tried using the update() function instead but to no avail. I am forced to use frozensets because I need a set of sets and this seems like the only solution in Python. The literal is just a list of one element of type String.

```py
    print(literal)
    print(clauses)
    clauses = clauses.add(frozenset(literal))
    print(clauses)
```

The output looks like this:

```
['!y']
{frozenset({'!y', 'z', 'x'})}
None
```

Comment: The set `add()` method modifies it "in-place" and doesn't return anything.

Comment: Or rather, it returns `None`, not the updated set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

> The methods that add, subtract, or rearrange their members in place,
>   and don’t return a specific item, never return the collection instance
>   itself but None.

That's why:

```
clauses = clauses.add(frozenset(literal))
```

means:

```
clauses.add(frozenset(literal))
clauses = None
```